# Update query that update single column

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my database i have a table of customer with one field of name which contains the name of the customer(first name and last name) in a single column now i want to write a query that search the first name and update its last name.
i would be appreciate if any one help me out.
thanks.

Comment: Sounds like First Name and Last Name should be separated into two columns...

Comment: search column using %firstname%, and update with firstname + UpdatedLastname

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati What if the name of the customer is `Foo Bar Baz`? What is the first name, what is the last name? We need more information to solve this question.

Comment: for example sameer shaikh, munaf shaikh, roman shaikh these are three name in where all first come first name and shaikh is last name of them. now i want to apply update query on this.@Ocaso Protal, @AlpeshPrajapati

Comment: you want only last name to be updated ??...and on what condition you want to search firstname...tell that also

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd25a/7  have a look at this

Answer (score 1):

This is not as easy as you maybe think. What you if someone has a second firstname? Where to cut?

This is why you normally normalize a database structure a create a column for the firstname and a column for the lastname.

Comment: yes i know the concept of normalization but i want to apply update query on that my requirement is like that.

Comment: for example sameer shaikh, munaf shaikh, roman shaikh these are three name in where all first come first name and shaikh is last name of them. now i want to apply update query on this

Comment: @SameerShaikh: The best way to address this problem is to fix the normalization of the data.  What you're attempting to do instead is to add to the problem by piling workarounds on top of it.  If you fix the problem, you will have fixed it.  If you add to the problem, you will have broken it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i **tried**

```
create table employeedemo
(id int, Name varchar(50), Location varchar(20))
```

---

```
insert into employeedemo values('1','Amir khan','India');
insert into employeedemo values('2','Salman khan','India');
insert into employeedemo values('3','Sharuk khan','India');
insert into employeedemo values('4','Saif khan','India');
insert into employeedemo values('5','Amit sarna','India');
insert into employeedemo values('6','Sanjay Dutt','India');
insert into employeedemo values('7','Sunny Deol','India');
```

---

```
update employeedemo
set name= 'Saif pataudi'
where SUBSTRING(Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',Name))='Saif'
```

---

Note: **Name column** must follow syntax as (firstname space lastname) n
vote up if its help :)